# Give a ModelSerializer, can I get related model fields used for QuerySet.only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I found my drf view is too slow due to **Fat SQL SELECT Clause** from DB.
So I want to select columns only required by bound serializer, thus I can write my view class like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='company_id')
    company_name = serializers.serializers.CharField(source='company.name')

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'company_id', 'company_name'
        )

class ListRetrieveProductViewSet(UpdateNonExistentMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.select_related(
            'company'
        ).only(*self.serializer_class.get_model_field_names())
```

`self.serializer_class.get_model_field_names()` may result `['id', 'name', 'company_id', 'company__name']`.

How to implement `get_model_field_names` or is there any existing implementations?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this another go. There is no automatic way (barring 3rd party packages) to do the company_name to company__name conversion. What you can do is create another variable under Meta:

```
class Meta:
    fields = (
        'id', 'name', 'company_id', 'company_name'
    )
    fields_for_query = (
        'id', 'name', 'company_id', 'company__name'
    )
```

then fetch it like so:

```
list(self.get_serializer_class().Meta.fields_for_query)
```

This approach makes it a bit more manageable since they're beside each other. Typically, you'd turn the fetch method into a mixin like so:

```
class FieldForQueryMixin(object):
    def get_field_for_query(self):
        assert hasattr(self.get_serializer_class().Meta, 'fields_for_query'), 'Serializer Meta is missing fields_for_query field yo.'
        return list(self.get_serializer_class().Meta.fields_for_query)

# use like so
class ListRetrieveProductViewSet(UpdateNonExistentMixin, FieldForQueryMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    pass
```

Comment: Serializer fields is not all directly derived from model fields. they may be from a model method, relation objects and something else.

Comment: Thanks! you gave a more elegant way than mine. BTW, `get_field_for_query` is not a drf-conventional view method.